# SignalR Core with Message Pack enabled, decimal deserialization from javacript fail

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net-core, signalr

When I send a message from a javascript client(web browser) to the SignalR server, with Message Pack enabled, and the object in the parameters contains a decimal, nothing happens, using other types as double works. I'm pretty sure that there is a problem with the deserialization of decimals from SignalR server.

```
public class StartParams
{
    public decimal first { get; set; }
    public decimal second { get; set; }
}
```

this object won't be deserialized from the server when I invoke, from the javascript page, connection.send("function", body); where body is StartParams. Trying to modify this class in

```
public class StartParams
{
    public double first { get; set; }
    public double second { get; set; }
}
```

all works fine. Is there a way to directly use the decimals in the DTO, without a type cast in the c# code?

Comment: Please let us know what version of .NET and MessagePack you're using

Comment: It could be that the culture of received obj is different then one set in your app. Can you try to for example add app.UseRequestLocalization(); on top of your Confugure method(startup class)

Comment: i'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.MessagePack version 5.0.7

Comment: I tried to change the culture in a way that was 100% uniformed with the input but nothing changed. Still the deserialization, from the parameters, of decimal doesn't work